# why there is no keyboard <kbd> in the menu?

Tags: support, feature-request, user-interface

We have included options for bold, italics, links, CODE, etc., but there is no option for keyboard keys.

For example to get Alt as a key we have to place it in between `<kbd>` tags then it will be as <kbd>Alt</kbd> but there is no option there in the body box menu.

Ff we place it then that could help the most new users while they do represent key combinations.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102841/163868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all sites in the Stack Exchange network require the input of `<kbd>` codes and even though the space can look big if we included all the possible edit aids on the toolbar we would be out of it in no time.

This can be added with the usage of [some simple scripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts) if you desire.

Comment: for ourselves can't we made a special request ? we need it right .

Comment: Read the edited part.

Comment: yup its good now